# Does TDengine support modify column type?

Tags: mysql, tdengine

As far as I know, we can change the type of column in MySQL, like

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY b INT NOT NULL;
```

I'm using TDengine, and I have lots of data stored. Now I want to change the type of one column from `tinyint` to `tinyint unsigned`.  I saw some examples in its document for adding/deleting columns.

Does anyone know how to modify the type information of a column?

Answer (score 0):

to modify the data type of the value column in the test table from `tinyint` to `tinyint unsigned`, you can use the following ALTER statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY value tinyint unsigned;
```

Let me know if it is helps.